Numba gives "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" with parallel=True flag set
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit(parallel=True)
def f(N):
    x = np.array([1.0], dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(N):
        y = x * 1.0
    return y


print(f(10000))

Running this code, Python crashes and outputs "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
If "N" is less than 5000, this code can give the correct result "[1.]".
Also If I change "range(N)" into "numba.prange(N)", or change "parallel=True" into "parallel=False", this code can also give the correct result.
I was puzzled here, it seems that numba's parallel has optimized "y=x*1.0", and a large "N" will make something overflow.
In my opinion, "range(N)" means executing in order and does not take account into parallel, and my real application scenario is like the following:
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
import numba as nb

@njit(parallel=True)
def f(N):
    x = np.array([1.0], dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(N):
        for j in nb.prange(100):
            some_function_here(some_args)
    return y

print(f(10000))

that is, I only need the loop of "j" is executed parallelly.
I wonder If I have missunderstood something here.

what version of numba are you using? I get the correct result with 0.59.0 with at least up to N=1000000 though it takes ages with parallel=True

@Nin17, I was using numba=0.58.1 and python=3.10.12. I just update numba to 0.59.0 and the problem is solved. It seems that this is a fixed bug. Thanks a lot.
